# Use Non-ASCII characters on SHOUTcast server song metadata

Tags: encoding, metadata, shoutcast

Using a `SHOUTcast` streaming service for a web radio that provides a server in `SHOUTcast v1.x`, in order to submit some song metadata, the server provides an API via HTTP calls, of the form:

```
http://SERVER_IP:PORT/admin.cgi?pass=PASSWORD&mode=updinfo&song=SONG_TITLE&....
```

These metadata can then be used by a variety of players in order to show these song information.

The problem is that if one wants to send *Greek* Characters (via `ISO 8859-7`, or `UTF-8` encoding), on the server the server will fail to get them correctly, probably because the server does not support such encoding, or some configuration is missing.

My question is, can there be passed any parameters to the API that will specify such encoding for the medadata? And, if this is not possible, are there any alternatives? (Would the move to `SHOUTcast v2` be a possible way to achieve this - via a new API or additional parameters, for instance?)

Comment: Do you know that Shoutcast 1.x is not longer supported in modern browsers? Move to 2.x, I guess it supports non-ascii characters if you encode them properly in your query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHOUTcast v1 will work with UTF-8 encoding if you correctly encode the URL. Note that the encoding isn't specified by the server, so the player has to support it.

Comment: There is no difference; server logs show garbage, so I guess it is a matter of the SHOUTcast server configuration. Any alternatives?

Comment: What's an example URL that you're sending in?

Comment: For the word "τεστ", which means simply, test: `...&song=%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%83%CF%84`

Comment: @NickL. Your URL looks correct to me.  It might be the case that the logging won't support UTF-8, but players will.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, but unfortunately this is not the case, as the players display "garbage" too.

Comment: @NickL. The players have to be configured to accept UTF-8.  This is often not by default.  (I know it works at least on some version of SHOUTcast v1... I remember doing it, but I don't remember the specific version. 1.9.8 maybe?)